# How to read from 3 List to a txt file

Tags: java, arraylist, java-io

I have 3 different ArrayList of object, items, stores and stock. I’m trying to read from those lists and print a single well formatted txt document called inventory. My issue is to read from more than one ArrayList. It works fine when I read and print from one List but not from many. I can’t figure this out.

Here is the code when I print from a single List.

```
public static void write(List<Item> items, PrintStream out) {

    out.println();
    out.println("Inventory Report");
    out.println("----------------");
    int i = 0;
    for (Item item : items) {
        out.format("%3d. %10s %50s %7.2f %3d%% %7.2f%n", ++i, item.getProductNumber(), item.getDescription(),
                (float) (item.getPrice() / 100.0), (int) (item.getDiscount() * 100),
                (float) (item.getSalePrice() / 100.0));
    }
}
```

And this is the output in my txt document:

### Inventory Report

1. 0210919                  Moto Precise Fit Rear Wiper Blade    7.99   0%    7.99
2. 83-4567-0       Easton Stealth Reflex Composite Hockey Stick   89.99  50%   44.99
3. 43-0439-6                    Tassimo T46 Home Brewing System  179.99  30%  125.99
4. 60-3823-0                       Yardworks 4-Ton Log Splitter  399.99   0%  399.99

Now, to print from 3 ArrayList I used the same pattern with 3 loops:

public static void write(List items, List stores, List stocks, PrintStream out) {

```
    out.println();
    out.println("Inventory Report");
    out.println("----------------");
    int i = 0;
    for (Item item : items) {
        for (Store store : stores) {
            for (Stock stock : stocks) {
                out.format("%3d. %10s %50s %7.2f %3d%% %7.2f %5s %20s %4d %7.2%n", ++i, item.getProductNumber(), item.getDescription(),
                        (float) (item.getRetailPrice() / 100.0), (int) (item.getDiscount() * 100),
                        (float) (item.getSalePrice() / 100.0), store.getStoreID(), store.getDescription(),
                        stock.getItemCount(), item.getRetailPrice() * stock.getItemCount());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

But my output gives me nothing:

### Inventory Report

Anyone has any ideas why it doesn’t print anything? I really don’t see why.
Thank you

**EDIT:**

My list are coming from 3 txt documents that I read from, maybe it's wrong there but I don't see why It would work for one but not for the other one. Here is my code:

```
public static List<?> read(File file) throws ApplicationException {


    Scanner scanner = null;
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new ApplicationException(e);
    }

    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    List<Store> stores = new ArrayList<Store>();
    List<Stock> stocks = new ArrayList<Stock>();

    try {
        scanner.nextLine();
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String row = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] elements = row.split("\\|");
            if (file.getName().equals("items.txt") && elements.length != 4) {
                throw new ApplicationException(String.format("Expected 4 elements but got %d", elements.length));
            } else if (file.getName().equals("stores.txt") && elements.length != 8) {
                throw new ApplicationException(String.format("Expected 8 elements but got %d", elements.length));
            } else if (file.getName().equals("stock.txt") && elements.length != 3) {
                throw new ApplicationException(String.format("Expected 3 elements but got %d", elements.length));
            }
            try {
                if (file.getName().equals("items.txt")) {
                    items.add(new Item(elements[0], elements[1], Integer.valueOf(elements[2]), Float
                            .valueOf(elements[3])));
                } else if (file.getName().equals("stores.txt")) {
                    stores.add(new Store(elements[0], elements[1], elements[2], elements[3], elements[4],
                            elements[5], elements[6], elements[7]));
                } else if (file.getName().equals("stock.txt")) {
                    stocks.add(new Stock(elements[0], elements[1], Integer.valueOf(elements[2])));
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                throw new ApplicationException(e);
            }
        }
        LOG.info("Input file successfully parsed.");
    } finally {

        if (scanner != null) {
            scanner.close();
        }
    }
    LOG.info("List of Input created");

    return items;
}
```

and that my txt documents that I read from:
Items.txt

-Description|SKU|Retail Price|Discount
-Tassimo T46 Home Brewing System|43-0439-6|17999|0.30
-Moto Precise Fit Rear Wiper Blade|0210919|799|0.0
-Easton Stealth Reflex Composite Hockey Stick|83-4567-0|8999|0.5
-Yardworks 4-Ton Log Splitter|60-3823-0|39999|0

Stores.txt

-ID|Description|Street|City|Province|Postal Code|Store Phone|Auto Service
-BC001|GRANDVIEW & BENTALL|2830 Bentall Street|Vancouver|BC|V5M 4H4|604-431-3570|604-431-3572
-BC002|BURNABY SOUTH| 7200 Market Crossing|Burnaby|BC|V5J 0A2|604-451-5888|604-451-5888

Stock.txt

-Store ID|Item SKU|Item Count
-BC001|43-0439-6|25
-BC001|60-3823-0|63
-BC001|83-4567-0|15
-BC001|0210919-0|2
-BC002|43-0439-6|12
-BC002|60-3823-0|47
-BC002|83-4567-0|32
-BC002|0210919-0|0

Comment: We need to see where do the lists come from, it seems that stores or stocks is empty.

Comment: Am I right? If each list have 3 elements then you will have 27 lines in the file? Is it that what you want?

Comment: I have 3 txt documents that I read from and output to a list each. @Marek what I want is one line for each items.

Comment: @Poupen. your mistake is that you always returns items list. So other lists would be empty. and your code in printing would not be work because only items list not empty other lists empty. You can check it during debug

Comment: It is not clear enough. You want to get one line for one item, for example: This type of BMW car is in that store with that stock. So Item can only be in one store?

Comment: You are returning items only, the other two lists are lost.

Comment: @Marek sorry, that's not clear. Basically for each stores, I need an inventory for each items. So if store 1 has 10 BMW and store 2 has 5 BMW, it would be two differents lines.

Comment: I see the return in my read method, thanks. But I can't return more than one list. I need to figure this out.

Comment: See my answer, can't you return a List<List<?>>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is that you always returns `items` list. So other lists would be empty. And your code in printing would not be work because only `items` list not empty other lists empty. You can check it during debug.

*If you want to fix your code you need to add if statements while returning and check according file name what list you need to return.*

Comment: Now when you showed us your code I can agree with that answer

Comment: he already write this code. he need the same if-else statements that he use to add elements to each list. Now he need to use this if-else statement to choose which list to return.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are only returning `List<Item> items`, I think you should return a `List<List<?>>` or a class that would wrap all the lists, then modify your write prototype like this:

```
public static void write(List<List<?>> lists, PrintStream out);
```

By the way you should not use un-typed parameters Like `List items` but `List<Items> items`.

```
List<List<?>> lists = new ArrayList<List<?>>();
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
List<Store> stores = new ArrayList<Store>();
List<Stock> stocks = new ArrayList<Stock>();

try
{
    ...
}
lists.add(items);
lists.add(stores);
lists.add(stocks);

return lists;
```

This compile for me with JDK 7:

```
public static List<List<?>> listOfList()
{
    List<List<?>> lists = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> items = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Double> stores = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Float> stocks = new ArrayList<>();

    lists.add(items);
    lists.add(stores);
    lists.add(stocks);

    return (lists);
}
```

You for loop becomes:

```
for (Item item : lists.get(0)) {
    for (Store store : lists.get(1)) {
        for (Stock stock : lists.get(2)) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you construct the List before?

Comment: Yes I did construct the List before.

Comment: compiler says that there is a syntax error.It doesn't say much. If I want to do that maybe I have to change more codes. I'm looking into it.

Comment: But in that case, if you do that you add everything to the same List, no?

Comment: No, if you want an item, you just need `lists.get(0).get(0)`, this will be the first list of lists, so items, and the first item of items. This is not very readable, but if you HAVE to use a List, this works.

Comment: I made it works using Aleksei Bulgak method. It was easier for me, but thanks for your help;) It actually works as well as you show, I just needed to make more changes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you made a mistake in formating?

```
%3d.    ++i
%10s    item.getProductNumber()
%50s    item.getDescription()
%7.2f   (float) (item.getRetailPrice() / 100.0)
%3d%%   (int) (item.getDiscount() * 100)
%7.2f   (float) (item.getSalePrice() / 100.0)
%5s     store.getStoreID()
%20s    store.getDescription()
%4d     stock.getItemCount()
%7.     item.getRetailPrice()
2%n"    stock.getItemCount()
```

//Sorry I just found out my mistake.